# making images responsive on my page doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've tried to make my page responsive but so far things aren't really working out. This is because of some images that become a certain precentage of their normal size instead of a percentage relative to my wrapper. I'd appreciate some help.  Thanks in advance,
Thijs

HTML:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
<div class = "menuitem">
<img src = "media/producten.png" class = "menuitemfoto">
</div>
<div class = "menuitem">
<img src = "media/info.png" class = "menuitemfoto">
</div>
<div class = "menuitem">
<img src = "media/fotos.png" class = "menuitemfoto">
</div>
<div class = "menuitem">
<img src = "media/contact.png" class = "menuitemfoto">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
width:1130px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.menuitem{
float:left;
padding-left: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1129px){
#wrapper{
width:100%
}

.menuitemfoto{
width: 25.7%;

}
}
```

Comment: why're you fixing their `width`, try setting `max-width: 100%` then it will only occupy its container and won't overflow either.

Comment: Yes but I want them to get smaller and that doesn't work that way. They just stay the same size. They don't get smaller because they just start going beneath each other I think

Comment: Create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net then the response time is more faster, not many are going to create a demo for you

Comment: the fiddle reacts really differently than my page for some reason...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t72uknLc/

Comment: the images start appearing beneath eachother when he page gets smaller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope this would help you. `http://jsfiddle.net/t72uknLc/1/`

Changes are -

```
.menuitem{
    display: inline;
}
.menuitemfoto{
    width: 24%;
}
```

Comment: no, sorry that didn't help. My page doesn't respond the same as the fiddle, for me the images just get ridiculously small and start jumping around the page... But thanks four your help anyway!